# How to change a Filter to access in explain plan in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, database-administration

I have two queries which are almost same except for few areas.
One of them is taking long time to execute and i.e. need to do some performance tuning.
On comparison with both the queries it was found out that the access in explain plan is present in the filter part of the other query. Please suggest how to change it to access for the query.

last part of explain plan for faster query and slower query respectively

```
287         150 - access("T1"."UNIT_TYPE"=:B1 AND "T1"."OBJECT_ID"=:B2 AND "T1"."PROPERTY_NAME"='X1' AND 
288                       "T1"."PROPERTY_TIMESTAMP"<=:B3)
289                filter("T1"."PROPERTY_VALUE" IS NOT NULL)
290         153 - access("T"."UNIT_TYPE"='G1' AND "T"."PROPERTY_NAME"='property_timestamp')
291                filter("T"."PROPERTY_NAME"='property_timestamp')


253                filter("T1"."PROPERTY_VALUE" IS NOT NULL)
254         132 - access("T1"."UNIT_TYPE"=:B1 AND "T1"."OBJECT_ID"=:B2 AND "T1"."PROPERTY_NAME"='X1' AND 
255                       "T1"."PROPERTY_TIMESTAMP"<=:B3)
256                filter("T1"."PROPERTY_VALUE" IS NOT NULL)
257         135 - filter("T"."PROPERTY_NAME"='property_timestamp' AND "T"."UNIT_TYPE"='G2')
```

need to convert the G2 like G1

Comment: you're going to need to give more detail before anyone can possibly help you with this

Comment: added the part which would help you

Comment: post both your queries and their plans

Comment: and the table definitions, included indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to change filter to access" is another way of asking "how do I use an index?"  It's a common question with many answers.  If you're familiar with the terms "access" and "filter" you've likely already tried common approaches, such as gathering statistics and using profiles.

A last resort for fixing complex execution plans is to use `+outline` to find the exact set of hints for a similar execution plan and copy them to the offending query.  This can be very complicated and requires undocumented features.

The `+outline` option displays a full set of hints to fix an execution plan.  The `+alias` option may also be helpful to identify the objects.

```
explain plan for select * from dba_objects;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'+outline +alias'));

...

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$3" "S"@"SEL$3" ("SUM$"."OBJ#"))
      FULL(@"SEL$5" "UE"@"SEL$5")
      BATCH_TABLE_ACCESS_BY_ROWID(@"SEL$6" "EO"@"SEL$6")
...
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */


...

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SET$1        / DBA_OBJECTS@SEL$1
   2 - SET$1       
   3 - SEL$3        / S@SEL$3
   4 - SEL$3        / S@SEL$3
...
```